# Foundation 4 topbar nav on mobile not showing

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I have a problem with Foundation 4 rendering on a small screen.
When on a local server i have the following html code, my custom css is turned of and so is my cutom js. All the needed libraries are loaded correctly as is the foundation library:

**Why isnt my topbar showing in a very small browser window?**

Below is a html snippet:

```
<div class="row show-for-touch show-for-portrait show-for-small">
    <nav class="top-bar">
        <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name">
                <h1><a href="index.php">title</a></h1>
            </li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <ul class="right">
                <li><h4><a href="#" class="navlink" id="dungeonmobile">Dungeon</a></h4></li>
                <li><h4><a href="#" class="navlink"id="pricinginformationmobile">Pricing information</a></h4></li>
                <li><h4><a href="#" class="navlink" id="contactmobile">Contact</a></h4></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to see your bar in a small browser if you add this visibility class: **show-for-touch**, which displays only on a real mobile environment.

If you like to see on a small browser, simply remove this class:

```
<div class="row show-for-portrait show-for-small">
```

[It works on this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/84oC1oaT4poHMmFwAqBW?p=preview).